# Random date with time in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle11g

Probably it's a stupid question but I didn't find anything on this topic.

How can I get a random date with associated a random time in Oracle? 
I mean, I need something like `20/02/2016 18:26:30` but generated randomly.
I can use the date type in oracle or I need another type?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
I need to get a random date and time in a defined interval. How can I do something like this?

Answer (score 3):

Would something like this do?

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> with test as
  2    (select date '2019-01-01' min_date,
  3            date '2019-01-31' max_date
  4     from dual
  5    )
  6  select min_date + dbms_random.value(0, level) new_date
  7  from test
  8  connect by level <= max_date - min_date;

NEW_DATE
-------------------
01.01.2019 09:12:46
02.01.2019 23:00:44
03.01.2019 06:53:47
03.01.2019 13:50:17
05.01.2019 05:13:33
02.01.2019 08:37:47
01.01.2019 12:07:08
08.01.2019 18:27:01
06.01.2019 18:45:57
10.01.2019 19:13:49
04.01.2019 15:22:32
02.01.2019 05:55:54
11.01.2019 20:17:50
10.01.2019 19:32:37
07.01.2019 21:54:26
06.01.2019 15:34:37
01.01.2019 20:47:33
02.01.2019 20:19:10
11.01.2019 02:00:46
07.01.2019 16:28:19
15.01.2019 11:47:29
06.01.2019 08:10:32
16.01.2019 01:00:22
14.01.2019 07:59:01
12.01.2019 10:03:16
21.01.2019 23:45:16
10.01.2019 02:34:24
17.01.2019 01:20:22
24.01.2019 07:39:40
16.01.2019 00:27:00

30 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering `DBMS_RANDOM` package might be useful

`select sysdate + DBMS_RANDOM.value(0,86400)/86400 * 7 from dual`

for upcoming one week as an example.

Or convert `7` to `30` for upcoming one month period of time.

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/UOI17268)</kbd>

Comment: But I think this solution will give me always the same time of sysdate. I mean, it will change only the day. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Paolopast you're right, you may try the case above to get changing time values.

Comment: Look at the edit. How Can I get the random date in a defined interval?